# Javascript date filtering accuracy issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, filter, datatable

I'm currently outputting data from an SQL query into a table and trying to filter it based on dates in two separate columns stored in a datatable. When I input a date into the filter, it is filtering it, but not accurately. I am storing the dates in EU format, and the data on the table does have a time, but the filter does not. I'm not sure if this is an issue with the EU format or the inclusion of time on the table.

I'm using the following code to minor success.

```
var minBeginDateFilter;
var maxBeginDateFilter;
var minEndDateFilter;
var maxEndDateFilter;

$.fn.dataTableExt.afnFiltering.push(
  function( oSettings, aData, iDataIndex ) {

    var startTime = new Date(aData[3]).getTime();
    var endTime = new Date(aData[4]).getTime();


    if ( minBeginDateFilter && !isNaN(minBeginDateFilter) ) {
      if ( startTime < minBeginDateFilter ) {
        return false;
      }
    }

    if ( maxBeginDateFilter && !isNaN(maxBeginDateFilter) ) {
      if ( startTime > maxBeginDateFilter ) {
        return false;
      }
    }

    if ( minEndDateFilter && !isNaN(minEndDateFilter) ) {
      if ( endTime < minEndDateFilter ) {
        return false;
      }
    }

    if ( maxEndDateFilter && !isNaN(maxEndDateFilter) ) {
      if ( endTime > maxEndDateFilter ) {
        return false;
      }
    }

    return true;
  }
);
$(document).ready(function(){
    //initTable("#itemTable");
    $("tr:odd").css("background-color", "#DBD4CE");
    $("tr:even").css("background-color", "#F9F1EA");
    $("#dialog").dialog({ autoOpen: false });  
    $("#dialog_link").click(function() {  
        $("#dialog").dialog("open");  
    });

    var oTable = $('#itemTable').dataTable( {
      "bJQueryUI": true
    } );

    $.datepicker.dateFormat = 'dd/mm/yy';

    $( "#beginFrom" ).datepicker( {
      "onSelect": function(date) {
        minBeginDateFilter = new Date(date).getTime();
        oTable.fnDraw();
      },
      dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy'
    } ).keyup( function () {
        minBeginDateFilter = new Date(this.value).getTime();
        oTable.fnDraw();
    } );

    $( "#beginTo" ).datepicker( {
      "onSelect": function(date) {
        maxBeginDateFilter = new Date(date).getTime();
        oTable.fnDraw();
      },
      dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy'
    } ).keyup( function () {
        maxBeginDateFilter = new Date(this.value).getTime();
        oTable.fnDraw();
    } );

    $( "#endFrom" ).datepicker( {
          "onSelect": function(date) {
            minEndDateFilter = new Date(date).getTime();
            oTable.fnDraw();
          },
          dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy'
    } ).keyup( function () {
        minEndDateFilter = new Date(this.value).getTime();
        oTable.fnDraw();
    } );

    $( "#endTo" ).datepicker( {
      "onSelect": function(date) {
        maxEndDateFilter = new Date(date).getTime();
        oTable.fnDraw();
      },
      dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy'
    } ).keyup( function () {
        maxEndDateFilter = new Date(this.value).getTime();
        oTable.fnDraw();
    } );
});
```

Table code:

```
<table id="itemTable" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Start Date & Time ${timeZone}</th>
        <th>End Date & Time ${timeZone}</th>
    </tr>
</thead>

<tbody>
    <c:forEach items="${marketAlerts}" var="marketAlert">       
        <tr id="item_${marketAlert.messageId}">             
            <td><fmt:formatDate pattern="${datePattern}" value="${marketAlert.eventStart}" /></td>
            <td><fmt:formatDate pattern="${datePattern}" value="${marketAlert.eventStop}" /></td>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Looking at the code. I'm noting that there is no notion that the date in the table is in EU format, so I am leaning towards that is the issue, but I'm not sure how to handle it.

Comment: What is the value of aData? Where is it coming from?

Comment: aData is the datatable itemTable. I implemented this functionality off of an example provided on this page http://live.datatables.net/etewoq/4/edit#javascript,live

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that the data you are getting from the db and the filters you are applying are of a different time zone? It should be noted that generic Date constructors in JavaScript assume the data is in the time zone of the web-client (your computer).

Comment: Should the time zone matter for a variance of just a few hours though? I'm getting inaccurate results to the tune of months, not just days.